# D: executeShell on Windows to run another program not returning immediately

Tags: windows, shell, d

I'm using D as a scripting language for Windows 7 console stuff to automate boring tasks. One of my scripts (open.exe) is supposed to allow me to open stuff from the command line without me having to specify which program I use (I have a configuration file with this stuff). Now, I use `executeShell` to do this, and call something like `start [name of program I want to use] [name of input file]`. If I do this directly from the shell, it returns immediately, but if I do it using my D script, it doesn't return until the program that it opens is closed. What should I do to allow it to return immediately?

For reference purposes, this is the business logic of my script (the main method just does some argument parsing for piping purposes):

```
immutable path = "some//path//going//to//config//file.conf";

void process(string input) {
string extension = split(input,".")[1]; //get file extension from input
auto config = File(path,"r"); auto found = false;
while (!config.eof()){
    auto line = chomp(config.readln());
    if (line[0]!='#') { //skip comment lines
        auto divided = split(line, ":");
        if (divided[0] == extension) {
            found = true;
            auto command = "start " ~ divided[1] ~ " " ~ input;
            auto result = executeShell(command);
            //test for error code and output if necessary
            writeln(result.output);
        }
    }
}
if (!found)
    writeln("ERROR: Don't know how to open " ~ input);
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the top of [the `std.process` documentation](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_process.html):

> Execute and **wait for completion**, collect output - `executeShell`

The Windows `start` program spawns a process and exits immediately. D's `executeShell` does something else. If you'd like to spawn another program, use the appropriate functions: `spawnProcess` or `spawnShell`.